# Tablesorter event source is not specific enough. Cancel sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting, events, tablesorter

I have a table that looks like this

[image]

And its HTML:

```
<th style="text-align: center; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: relative; top: 0px; -moz-user-select: none;" data-column="4" class="tablesorter-header tablesorter-headerDesc" tabindex="0" scope="col" role="columnheader" aria-disabled="false" aria-controls="dataTable" unselectable="on" aria-sort="descending" aria-label="DI: Descending sort applied, activate to apply an ascending sort" data-sortedby="user">
    <div class="tablesorter-header-inner">
        <i onclick="javascript:ShowFilter(event,'dDICategory');" class="fa fa-filter"/>
        <i class="fa fa-sort-asc sort-icon"/>
        <i class="fa fa-sort-desc sort-icon"/>
        <i class="fa fa-sort sort-icon"/>DI<div id="helpIcon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#DIColumnHelpModal">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign pull-right"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</th>
```

As you can see I have a filter, sorting up and down pointers and a help icon.

My problem is that when I click the question mark, the table gets sorted before showing me the help modal. And I don't want.

I would like to be able to do the following:

If the event source is sort-asc or sort-desc glyph then let the sorting event to continue.
If the event source is the filter glyph, do not sort and execute ShowFilter function.
If the event source is question mark glyph, do not sort and show modal.

So I need to get the actual source of the event (sort-asc/sort-desc, filter or question mark). But the problem is that what I get when I check the content of event.target is the whole table. I don't know how to get more specific answer.

And of course, once I knew which glyph fired the event, I think I would need to cancel sorting event.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `tablesorter-noSort` class name to the filter icon element; see the [`cssNoSort` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#cssnosort) if you want to rename that class.